# Outlook Web add-in - localstorage is cleared between messages

Tags: internet-explorer-11, outlook-web-addins

I need your help.

OS: Windows Server 2019
IE11: version 1809

I believe Outlook win app is using that IE11 as embedded web viewer. I save some data in localStorage, but when I select another message and open my web add-in and my localStorage keys do not exist. It looks like they are cleared "on exit'? Anybody faced such problem?

Thanks

AU

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue using a simple `localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")` and `localStorage.getItem("foo")`. What is your Outlook version number? We have documentation here on how to persist data, with solutions other than localStorage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings

Comment: Thank you. What I spotted is if I run the Outllook as admin, then localStorage is not cleared between messages. I am using not activated version yet, just for testing. Version 2012 (Build 13530.20376). View Only(Unlicensed) Microsoft 365 Apps for business.

Comment: localStorage is working fine for that selected message, I can add and get values, but if I select next message and open the web addin again then I can't see my keys :(

Comment: If you store data in localStorage while running Outlook as admin, are you able to access that data when running Outlook not as admin?

Comment: Also, can you try using localStorage in a simple webpage in IE 11, outside of an add-in to see if you have the same problem? You can do this by using this test page from w3schools.com : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_localstorage. It allows you to modify the code in the browser and execute it.

Comment: No, I can't access localStorage not as admin after. I tried to run w3school site and actually it throws some errors: https://prnt.sc/xg2yfj. When I click the button I get SCRIPT206: The filename or extension is too long. If I run IE11 as admin it looks fine. It sounds like IE11 configuration issue? Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The error you are getting with the w3schools.com page appears to be specific to that page. Try creating a simple webpage on your own to test out IE11 and localStorage so as to minimize the noise in the error console. Then let us know the unique error.

Comment: I created a simple page to use localStorage. And I am getting {"description":"The filename or extension is too long.\r\n","number":-2147024690,"stack":"Error: The filename or extension is too long.\r\n\n at Global code (https://servername/da-eoffice-addin/index.html?apptype=Outlook&_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.02$en-US$$$$0:16:3)"}. But, I don't get if I run the Outlook as admin. I can see Smith value. And I don't get the error in IE11.

Comment: The issue happens in MS Word and MS Excel too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what JS code is returning the "filename or extension is too long" error. To bypass problems with other code running in the webpage, could you try calling the localStorage API directly from the debugging window in IE11? Since it works inside Outlook (at least within a single session), I would also expect the API to work in IE11. Then, my question is, if you re-open the webpage in IE11 and call the API again, is the data retrieved or is localStorage cleared between sessions?

Comment: OK, ignore what I said. I have very simple web app: <html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

<div>hellow world 7</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>

try
{
 localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
}
catch(error)
{
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error.message;
}

</script>
</body></html>

Comment: And it throws the error "The filename or extension is too long." See the pic https://prnt.sc/xszo5k. It doesn't throw the error in IE11 web browser. Only in Outlook. I am lost :D. I restored IE11 settings to defaults.

Comment: Also, the same happens in MS Word and Excel apps.

Comment: I think I have found what is that. It looks like a user was missing access rights to \AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore. I ran icacls %userprofile%\Appdata\LocalLow /t /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L. It looks like it is working as expected now. It's a wonderful MS world I'd say :D .Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Thanks for diagnosing the issue. If this fixed the issue for you, feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A regular user was missing the access rights to \AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore. I ran icacls %userprofile%\Appdata\LocalLow /t /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L and it solved my issue.