# Outlook Add-in cookies cleared in desktop app, but why localStorage works?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Related question: [Outlook Web add-in - localstorage is cleared between messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811553/outlook-web-add-in-localstorage-is-cleared-between-messages)

My question here is why are cookies cleared but localStorage retained for Outlook Add-ins used on the Outlook desktop app? I would have thought that both would have worked in the same way. It seems to me that clearing cookies is a bug in the way Outlook uses the Edge webviews.

Answer (score 0):

By cookies, I believe you are referring to session cookies. In other words, cookies without an expiry date. When the add-in is closed, the underlying browser is also closed, hence the session cookies are deleted. More info on cookie lifetimes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). You can compare this behavior to sessionStorage, not localStorage. So, try setting an expiry date on your cookies to preserve them beyond the add-in session.

Keep in mind that we don't preserve session cookies for the entire item session (or Outlook session). We only preserve them for the lifetime of the add-in instance.

Refer to this similar known issue for more information:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/846

Comment: Hi Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, thanks for your response. I confirmed that the cookies are setup with an expiration of 3 years. Also this used to work correctly in old versions of Outlook/Windows. which I believe were using IE (Internet Explorer) and not Edge. I appreciate your taking the time to respond but it does not help with my issue in any way. Please note that the cookies retain correctly on the outlook.com web app, but does not retain correctly when running the same code on the desktop Outlook. Please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What are your Outlook and Windows build numbers?

Comment: Outlook - Version 2109 (Build 14430.20306 Click-to-Run), Current Channel
Windows - Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 21H1, OS Build 19043.1288

Can you please confirm if persisting cookies correctly is something that could be fixed soon? This used to work. Thanks!

Comment: Persistent cookies should work for Edge Webview2. Could you provide repro steps?

Comment: Repro:
1. Install Dropbox for Outlook add-in (https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/third-party/outlook-email)
2. Open add-in from outlook.com
3. Sign in to any dropbox account
4. Close the add-in
5. Open the add-in again --> it will stay signed-in.
6. Open desktop Outlook app
7. Open add-in from the desktop Outlook app.
8. Sign-in to any dropbox account.
9. Close add-in.
10. Open add-in again --> it will get signed out of Dropbox account (should have stayed signed-in).
Note that there is no way (that I know of) to inspect the JS from the desktop Outlook app). Thanks!

Comment: In Outlook desktop, you can open a debugger by right clicking on the taskpane and clicking "Inspect" to open the debugger. Or you can follow these debugging instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, but that doesn't resolve the issue. Cookies still get lost.

Comment: We currently are unable to repro your issue on our end, does this repro for you on different machines? and is it possible to get/provide a fiddler trace for when this happens?

Comment: That can't be right. Can you please confirm what is your desktop Outlook version? Is it older or newer than my version? Btw you can check this with the Dropbox for Outlook add-in. Web outlook - you will stay signed-in after closing the add-in. Desktop outlook - you will get auto signed out after closing the add-in. Thanks.

Comment: We tried using similar/slightly newer versions of desktop Outlook, but we do not expect Outlook version to be the issue. Could you confirm that your setup is using Edge Webview2 as expected (did "Inspect" work to bring up Microsoft Edge DevTools?). Could you also provide snippet of the cookie related code? It would be helpful for us to try repro outside of the dropbox addin.